# How to check whether a particular url path is a directory or not in KMM ios implementation?

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I want to covert the corresponding swift method into kotlin for kmm

```
func checkIfDirectoryExist(fileURL: URL) -> Bool {
     var isDir: ObjCBool = false
     if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path, isDirectory: &isDir)
     {
         if isDir.boolValue {
             return true
         } else {
             return false
         }
      }
        return false
}
```

However I am not sure hot to pass Boolean pointer in kotlin as there are no `toCPointer<Boolean>()` method neither `**` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with Objective-C APIs in Kotlin/Native can be complicated. In many cases such as this one, you're actually interacting with elements of C such as pointers and memory allocation.

## Understanding memory use for the `isDirectory` boolean in Swift

Given the Swift code that you wrote:

```swift
var isDir: ObjCBool = false
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path, isDirectory: &isDir) {
   ...
```

If we consider how this code is running it might help to understand how to write this in Kotlin/Native:

- The `isDir` variable is defined as an `ObjCBool` type.
- When passing `isDir` to the `fileExists()` method, an `&` is used in order to pass the variable by *reference* (read/write), not by *value* (read only).
- The `fileExists()` method not only returns the boolean indicator of whether the file exists or not, but it also populates the value of the `isDir` variable with the result (often in Swift referred to as `in/out`).
- [Apple's Objective-C documentation for this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410277-fileexistsatpath) may also be a helpful reference as this shows that the `isDirectory` argument is a pointer to a boolean (`BOOL *`), as opposed to the return value of the method which is just a boolean (`BOOL`).

## Allocating memory for `isDir` in K/N using `memScoped` and `alloc`

In Kotlin/Native, we need to allocate memory for the `isDir` variable to be populated, which relies on leveraging the `kotlinx.cinterop` suite of methods.

Using [`memscoped`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/mem-scoped.html) will allocate memory for use within the block passed as an argument and deallocate that memory when the scope closes. You can see in the declaration of the function that whatever type we return from the block (`R`) will be the same value returned from the call to `memScoped` (`R`):

`inline fun <R> memScoped(block: MemScope.() -> R): R`

The `MemScoped` object allows calling [the `alloc` method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/alloc.html) to allocate memory for use within this block, and we need to allocate memory for a `BooleanVar`. Note that `alloc` returns type `T` which conforms to `CVariable`.

```kotlin
memScoped {
    val isDirectory = alloc<BooleanVar>()
    ...
}
```

## Populating the value of `isDirectory`

When calling the `fileExists()` method in K/N, if we check the K/N header declaration we can see what it expects to receive for arguments (formatted for readability). Note the `isDirectory` parameter is a `CPointer` pointing to a `BooleanVar`. This is how we knew to allocate memory for a `BooleanVar` and not some other kind of type:

```kotlin
@kotlinx.cinterop.ObjCMethod 
public open external fun fileExistsAtPath(
    path: kotlin.String, 
    isDirectory: kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<kotlinx.cinterop.BooleanVar>?
): kotlin.Boolean
```

Therefore, with the memory that we allocated, which is of type [`CVariable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/-c-variable/), we can pass the pointer to that memory (passing by reference) for the `fileExistsAtPath` method to change the value of it:

```kotlin
val fileExists = NSFileManager.defaultManager.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory.ptr)
                                                                                 ^^^
```

Lastly, getting the value populated into the `BooleanVar` `CVariable` is accessed from the `.value` property.

Together, the code might look something like:

```kotlin
return memScoped {
    val isDirectory = alloc<BooleanVar>()
    val fileExists = NSFileManager.defaultManager.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory.ptr)
    return@memScoped fileExists && isDirectory.value
}
```

## iOS URL

As for converting the entire method, this is getting a bit into API generalization. You'll need to convert the `URL` argument to a platform-independent type, such as a simple path (string). This appears to be unrelated to your original question, so although I'll leave this detail out, you might find [this blog post helpful](https://medium.com/kodein-koders/create-a-kotlin-multiplatform-library-with-swift-1a818b2dc1b0).

## If you want to go deeper

[Kotlin/Native has some documentation on its interoperability with C](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html), however admittedly, I find this documentation a bit difficult to understand with the provided example.

Comment: If you want to dig deeper, I also published a blog post on writing iOS-platform-dependent code using Kotlin with KMM's expect/actual: https://artandscienceofcoding.com/science/avoid-this-kmm-technique/